# How to make Django query using extra() portable accross database backends?

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql

I have a little project that involved article archive browsing by year of publication.

I used the trick given in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968764/how-to-use-django-orm-to-get-a-list-by-year-of-all-articles-with-an-article-count) to build a list of article publication years and article counts for those years. It works pretty well on my test server with SQLite. Since the production server will rely on PostgreSQL I am looking for a way to achieve the same thing in PostgreSQL and ended up toying with the EXTRACT keyword. I use something like "import settings" to detect the current database backend and execute the right query.

My point is all of that look more and more like a dirty & crappy hack to solve an issue in a very inelegant, untestable and poorly maintainable way. As a web programmer beginner I ask my experienced elder,

How would you deal with that correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option to the raw sql:

You can calculate the count per year with the ORM  (e.g. [How to use Django ORM to get a list by year of all articles with an article count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968764/how-to-use-django-orm-to-get-a-list-by-year-of-all-articles-with-an-article-count/3971955#3971955) )

Then you store that value somewhere (in a model or in cache ...) in order not to be overwhelmed by the slowness of the ORM calculation.

Comment: A one-request solution looked quite sexy to me since I believe this kind of processing can be done very efficiently by the database software (after all, that's part of its job). But if I can't do better than a multi-requests + caching combo I'll go for that.
Thanks for the answer any-way.

Comment: Well I wasn't happy to rely on caching but Django made that quite easy. And my poor Webfaction host doesn't seems to drown under the database query, so I'll go for that.